# Using Matlab 'find' in a 3D logical array along the 3rd dimension only

Tags: matlab, find

I have a 3D logical array, for example:

```
A = randi([0 1],x,y,z);
```

where x,y,z are integers.

Is there a way to find the first true value along the 3rd dimension 'z', for each (x,y)?

I can do it in a loop like this:

```
B = zeros(x,y);

for ix = 1:x
    for iy = 1:y
        B(ix,iy) = find(A(ix,iy,:),1,'first');
    end
end
```

Is there an array operation which will allow me to do it without a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a very straightforward one.

That is because there may not *be* a `true` anywhere along the third dimension.

By the way, what you're doing may lead to an *extremely* hard to find bug. If it is the case that there is no true value somewhere, `find` will return the empty matrix (`[]`). And, assigning an empty matrix to something in MATLAB will *delete* that element from the array you're assigning to.

Meaning:

1. `B(ix,iy)` will be deleted
2. The number of elements in your `B` will shrink by 1
3. All subsequent results will be assigned to the wrong positions in `B`
4. When you've reached the end of `A` (and are thus now indexing beyond the boundary of `B`), MATLAB will automatically grow the array `B` to fit your assignment.

You'll be none the wiser, but all the results are meaningless garbage.

Luckily, MATLAB throws a warning if you're doing that on arrays with dimension larger than 1, ***BUT***, if you're using the same technique on *vectors* (e.g., `B` is a vector), MATLAB will not warn you.

So, at the very least, do a check:

```
for ix = 1:x
    for iy = 1:y
        if any(A(ix,iy,:))
            B(ix,iy) = find(A(ix,iy,:), 1, 'first'); 
        end
    end
end
```

Also note that `any` can take a second argument specifying the dimension to "`any`" over, meaning

```
any(A,3)
```

will return an `x×y` array of logicals, containing `true` if there is a `true` in `A` along its third dimension, and `false` otherwise. This may help you prevent having to compute the indices explicitly (oftentimes, they are not really explicitly needed if you change paradigm).

Now, having said all that, you could use

```
[~, B] = max(A ~= 0, [], 3);
```

but you'd still have to do checks on all-zeros:

```
B(~any(A, 3)) = 0;
```

I'd say, the loop with the check is just *so* much more intuitive that it'd have my preference. However, the `max` technique is about 7 times faster, so when properly documented (probably with the loop as part of the comment above it, as well as in an accompanying unit test), then well, why not.